# Как подсчитать количество правильных ответов?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать код, в котором в конце будет подсчитываться количество правильных ответов?

```js
var radiosE = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']:checked");
radiosE.forEach(function(radio) {
    var res = 0;
    var lableId = "text" + radio.id;
    var lable = document.getElementById(lableId);
    var rA = radio.parentElement.dataset.answer; 

    if (rightAns[rA] == radio.value) {
        lable.classList.add("correct");
    } else {
        lable.classList.add("wrong");
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

- Строку `var res = 0;`  выносишь **ЗА** цикл
- Внутри блока `if (rightAns[rA] == radio.value)` дописываешь `res++;`
- За циклом выводишь `res`